# why is my program not using the methods I have written?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

The given program compiles, but doesn't run the way I want it though. I think it's not applying the methods I wrote. any ideas?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Assignment_1_q1 {

    static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static int i;
    public static int counter;
    public static int n;

    //main method
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Enter n's value: " );
        n = input.nextInt(); //Prompts the user to input the integer number n.
        int[] table = new int[10]; //Create an array of size 10.
        getArrayValues(table); //Calls the first method
        matchCriteria(table, counter, n); //Calls the second methods 
        System.out.println("There is "+ n +"numbers greater than n!" ); //display the result.

    }
    //the first method to input array values from the user,
    //allows nonnegative numbers only to be stored into the array.
    public static int[] getArrayValues(int table[]){

        while (table[i] < 0)
        System.out.println("Pleas try a nonnegative number!" );

       for (int i = 0; table[i] < table.length; i++){           
           System.out.println("Enter an array value: ");
           table[i] = input.nextInt();           
         }
       return table;
  }
    // the second method determines how many of array values are greater than the value of n.
    public static int matchCriteria(int array[], int counter, int n){

        counter = 0; 

        for(int i = 0; i < array.length && i > n;) {
            if (i > n) counter++;
        }
        return counter;
  }

}
```

Comment: You aren't storing (or using) the results of invoking your methods.

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the result of getArrayValues() to table as such:

```
table = getArrayValues(table);

int newcounter =  matchCriteria(table, counter, n);
```

On top of that, realize your for loop is using table[i] instead of i in the selection criteria. it would be better to do it in a while loop:

Consider refactoring as such:

```
for (int i = 0; i < table.length; i++){           
       System.out.println("Enter an array value: ");
       table[i] = input.nextInt();
       while(table[i] < 0) {
           System.out.println("Pleas try a nonnegative number!" );
           table[i] = input.nextInt();
       }
     }
```

Comment: great, that did help with the output, however it's still letting the user enter negative numbers

Comment: that's okay @KhaledBoustati, it should allow the user to enter negative numbers, but it will not save them to the table until they enter a positive number. 

If you want to halt the program on a negative input, consider throwing an exception.

Answer (score -1):

Like Elliott said, you aren't really doing anything with the data from invoking the methods. You have to use that depending on what you're trying to do.